# Add borders to cells in POI generated Excel File

Tags: java, excel, border, apache-poi

I am using POI to generate an Excel File.  I need to add borders to specific cells in the worksheet.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Setting up borders in the style used in the cells will accomplish this.  Example:

```
style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I am still open to better solutions. Especially ones that don't involve new styles just to change the border.

Comment: Styles are the most common way to do it, Excel generally does these sorts of things with either styles or drawings.

Comment: @Gagravarr, thanks.  I guess it just seemed like a pain to have to have to have two styles for the same text, but one that has border and one that doesn't.  Especially if you wanted a stronger border around the outer edges.  I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is try doing it in Excel, and see what Excel itself does in the file. I've a strong suspicion that you'll see that Excel'll create styles to do it...

Answer (score 38):

In the newer apache poi versions:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
```

Answer (score 25):

```
HSSFCellStyle style=workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
```

Answer (score 15):

### XSSF

#### BorderStyle

Use `XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM` or `XSSFBorderFormatting.BORDER_MEDIUM` (both enums refer to the same value):

```
final XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

cellStyle.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
cellStyle.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
cellStyle.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

#### BorderColor

Use `setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.BOTTOM, XSSFColor)` or `setBottomBorderColor(XSSFColor)` (equivalent for top, left, right):

```
final XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
final XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128));

cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(color);
cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(color);
cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(color);
cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(color);

cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: Great job @winklerrr finally someone who reads questions! It is XSSF not HSSF

Answer (score 15):

a Helper function:

```
private void setRegionBorderWithMedium(CellRangeAddress region, Sheet sheet) {
        Workbook wb = sheet.getWorkbook();
        RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
        RegionUtil.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, region, sheet, wb);
    }
```

When you want to add Border in Excel, then

```
String cellAddr="$A$11:$A$17";
```

`setRegionBorderWithMedium(CellRangeAddress.valueOf(cellAddr1), sheet);`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the **org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel** (not HSSF or XSSF) you can use:

```
style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
```

all the border styles are [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html) at the apache documentation

Answer (score 3):

From Version 4.0.0 on `RegionUtil`-methods have a new signature. For example:

```
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.DOUBLE,
            CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B7"), sheet);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a border in Apache POI you should...

1: Create a style

```
final XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

2: Then you have to create the border

```
style.setBorderBottom( new XSSFColor(new Color(235,235,235));
```

3: Then you have to set the color of that border

```
style.setBottomBorderColor( new XSSFColor(new Color(235,235,235));
```

4: Then apply the style to a cell

```
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```