# Apache POI: Diagonal border in XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I found the [XSSFCellBorder](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/extensions/XSSFCellBorder.html) to support diagonal border styles as well and I want to use them, but I haven't found any way to get a `XSSFCellBorder` from an `XSSFCellStyle` so I can apply them in [the usual way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720049/add-borders-to-cells-in-poi-generated-excel-file).
How can I set the diagonal border for a `Cell`, preferrably via `Style`s?

Comment: There is an answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529042/apache-poi-how-to-add-diagonal-border

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI: How to add Diagonal Border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529042/apache-poi-how-to-add-diagonal-border)