# Apache POI: How to add Diagonal Border

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like to use `Apache POI` to draw `Diagonal Border` but I couldn't find any function can support that feature.

[image]

I tried this [setBorderDiagonal](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/cf/BorderFormatting.html#setBorderDiagonal(int)) but it isn't working.

```
XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting my_cond_format_layer = my_sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

XSSFConditionalFormattingRule my_rule = my_cond_format_layer.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.BETWEEN, "14", "16");
XSSFConditionalFormattingRule my_rule_2 = my_cond_format_layer.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "33");
XSSFPatternFormatting fill_pattern_2 = my_rule_2.createPatternFormatting();
fill_pattern_2.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());

XSSFBorderFormatting borderFormatting = my_rule_2.createBorderFormatting();
borderFormatting.setDiagonalBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
borderFormatting.setBorderDiagonal(BorderFormatting.BORDER_THICK);

ConditionalFormattingRule[] multiple_rules = {my_rule, my_rule_2};
CellRangeAddress[] my_data_range = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A4")};
my_cond_format_layer.addConditionalFormatting(my_data_range, multiple_rules);
```

Comment: Is this question about HSSF only? If not, for XSSF may be a solution. Not for HSSF, at least not from me. @Luc: As a member for 3 years you should know that such irritations would be unnecessary if one would show the code which "isn't working".

Comment: @AxelRichter: You're right. My mistake. I have updated my question. If there is solution for XSSF, hope you can provide.

Comment: @Luc, It's also possible to use same for XSSF, check XSSFBorderFormatting.setBorderDiagonal

Comment: In conditional formatting? No, Excel cannot set diagonal borders in conditional formatting. Try it in Excel itself. It will not be possible because diagonal borders are greyed out in conditional formatting.

Comment: @AxelRichter: How about in normal case? When I have `cell` and I just want to set diagonal border. (Without conditional formatting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why there is not a `setBorderDiagonal` in `XSSFCellStyle` until now. But if we take a look at the code of the other `setBorder...` methods, then we could make our own `setBorderDiagonal`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.extensions.XSSFCellBorder;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTXf;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorder;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorderPr;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STBorderStyle;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class CellDiagonalBorders {

 private static CTBorder getCTBorder(StylesTable _stylesSource, CTXf _cellXf ){
  CTBorder ct;
  if(_cellXf.getApplyBorder()) {
   int idx = (int)_cellXf.getBorderId();
   XSSFCellBorder cf = _stylesSource.getBorderAt(idx);
   ct = (CTBorder)cf.getCTBorder().copy();
   } else {
    ct = CTBorder.Factory.newInstance();
   }
  return ct;
 }

 public static void setBorderDiagonal(short border, StylesTable _stylesSource, CTXf _cellXf , ThemesTable _theme) {
  CTBorder ct = getCTBorder(_stylesSource, _cellXf);
  CTBorderPr pr = ct.isSetDiagonal() ? ct.getDiagonal() : ct.addNewDiagonal();
  if(border == BorderFormatting.BORDER_NONE) {
   ct.unsetDiagonal();
  }
  else {
   ct.setDiagonalDown(true);
   ct.setDiagonalUp(true);
   pr.setStyle(STBorderStyle.Enum.forInt(border + 1));
  }
  int idx = _stylesSource.putBorder(new XSSFCellBorder(ct, _theme));    
  _cellXf.setBorderId(idx);
  _cellXf.setApplyBorder(true);   
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(2);

   CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

   StylesTable _stylesSource = ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource();
   ThemesTable _theme = _stylesSource.getTheme();
   CTXf _cellXf = ((XSSFCellStyle)style).getCoreXf();

   setBorderDiagonal(BorderFormatting.BORDER_THICK, _stylesSource, _cellXf, _theme);

   cell.setCellStyle(style);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CellDiagonalBorders.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

Edit February 23 2018:
Above code had worked for previous versions of `apache poi`. Following code works in actual latest stable version `3.17`:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.extensions.XSSFCellBorder;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTXf;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorder;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTBorderPr;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STBorderStyle;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class CellDiagonalBorders {

 private static CTBorder getCTBorder(StylesTable _stylesSource, CTXf _cellXf ) {
  CTBorder ct;
  if(_cellXf.getApplyBorder()) {
   int idx = (int)_cellXf.getBorderId();
   XSSFCellBorder cf = _stylesSource.getBorderAt(idx);
   ct = (CTBorder)cf.getCTBorder().copy();
   } else {
    ct = CTBorder.Factory.newInstance();
   }
  return ct;
 }

 public static void setBorderDiagonal(BorderStyle border, StylesTable _stylesSource, CTXf _cellXf, ThemesTable _theme) {
  CTBorder ct = getCTBorder(_stylesSource, _cellXf);
  CTBorderPr pr = ct.isSetDiagonal() ? ct.getDiagonal() : ct.addNewDiagonal();
  if(border == BorderStyle.NONE) {
   ct.unsetDiagonal();
  }
  else {
   ct.setDiagonalDown(true);
   ct.setDiagonalUp(true);
   pr.setStyle(STBorderStyle.Enum.forInt(border.getCode() + 1));
  }
  int idx = _stylesSource.putBorder(new XSSFCellBorder(ct, _theme, _stylesSource.getIndexedColors()));    
  _cellXf.setBorderId(idx);
  _cellXf.setApplyBorder(true);   
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);

  CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
  style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THICK);
  style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THICK);

  StylesTable _stylesSource = null;
  if (wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) {
   _stylesSource = ((SXSSFWorkbook)wb).getXSSFWorkbook().getStylesSource();
  } else if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   _stylesSource = ((XSSFWorkbook)wb).getStylesSource();
  }
  if (_stylesSource != null) {
   ThemesTable _theme = _stylesSource.getTheme();
   CTXf _cellXf = ((XSSFCellStyle)style).getCoreXf();
   setBorderDiagonal(BorderStyle.DOUBLE, _stylesSource, _cellXf, _theme);
  }

  style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THICK);
  style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THICK);

  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  for (int r = 1; r < 1000; r++) {
   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(r).createCell(2);
   cell.setCellStyle(style);
  }

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CellDiagonalBorders.xlsx");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  wb.close();
  if (wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) ((SXSSFWorkbook)wb).dispose();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's great. I don't know about `StylesTable`, `ThemesTable`, `CTXf`. New experience!!!