# Apache poi cell diagonal strikethrough

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel

How can I strikethrough diagonally a cell in excel using Apache poi?

I want to get something like this:

[image]

I have tried:

```
cell.getCellStyle().setFillPattern(CellStyle.THIN_BACKWARD_DIAG)
```

but then the cell is having many diagonal lines instead of one from top right to bottom left.

**Edit:**
This is how I create the workbook:

```
Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test");
```

Then creating the columns and the rows, I don't see there any special to show.

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529042/apache-poi-how-to-add-diagonal-border/39536304#39536304

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529042/apache-poi-how-to-add-diagonal-border/39536304#39536304 again. I have added code which works in actual latest stable version apache poi 3.17 and supports `SXSSFWorkbook` too.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that part of code.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my previous answer, currently there is no diagonal border available readily in apache poi, though we can write our own custom method. You can use below method which will add a diagonal border in a cell.

```
public static void setDiagonal(StylesTable stylesSource, CTXf cellXtraFormating, ThemesTable theme) {
    CTBorder ct = CTBorder.Factory.newInstance();
    CTBorderPr pr = ct.addNewDiagonal();
    ct.setDiagonalUp(true);
    pr.setStyle(STBorderStyle.Enum.forInt(BorderFormatting.BORDER_THIN + 1));
    int idx = stylesSource.putBorder(new XSSFCellBorder(ct, theme));
    cellXtraFormating.setBorderId(idx);
    cellXtraFormating.setApplyBorder(true);
  }
```

call the above method in your class like this

```
    CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
    StylesTable styleSource = ((XSSFWorkbook) workbook).getStylesSource();
    ThemesTable theme = styleSource.getTheme();
    CTXf cellXtraFormating = ((XSSFCellStyle) cs).getCoreXf();
    -------your custom code---------
    setDiagonal(styleSource, cellXtraFormating, theme);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);
```

I hope this answers your question

[image]

Comment: I was doing exactly the same thing...But as I mentioned in the question I want a **single** diagonal line instead of many diagonal lines. There is nothing wrong in my code if I want the same result you mentioned...

Comment: It seems it is okay, but when I want to try it I realized I have `SXSSFWorkbook` not `XSSFWorkbook`, how can I do with this type?