# How to add Borders for all four sides for a range of dynamically generated cells using java in XSSFWorkbook [xlsx File]

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

How to add Borders for all four sides for a range of dynamically generated cells using java in XSSFWorkbook .

```
XSSFSheet objSheet = objWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
objSheet.shiftRows(5, objSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1, 10, true, true);
```

I have used this code.
I am getting cells generated but i want to add all side borders for the generated cells.

Comment: Please go through this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720049/add-borders-to-cells-in-poi-generated-excel-file

Comment: I tried    style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);   but it is only to set for a particular cell. but i need it for a range .(Not setting each cell value manually )

Comment: style.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
  style.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
  style.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
  style.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);   using xssf document

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Borders, specifically

```
// Create a cell and put a value in it.
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(4);

// Style the cell with borders all around.
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM_DASHED);
style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

If you want to have it for more cells you will need to iterate over them and apply the style to each of those.

Make sure to apply the same style-object to as many cells as possible, the Excel format has limits on how many styles you can have in one file.